# Not obvious limit which is zero. How to prove it?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am unamble to find the limit.$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^{n}+2^{n}+...+n^{n}}{n^{n+1}}$$
I have tried even the Stoltz theorem but it still gives me nothing. Does anyone has an idea how to approach it. I have checked it using wolframalpha and it returns 0 but I am unable to prove it. Please help !!!

I received an answer like this one below:

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {\sum_\limits{k=1}^n k^n}{n^n} = \frac {n^n + (n-1)^n + (n-2)^n \cdots}{n^n}\\
\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} 1 + (1 - \frac {1}{n})^n + (1 - \frac {2}{n})^n \cdots\\
1 + e^{-1} + e^{-2} + e^{-3} \cdots\\
\frac {e}{e-1}$

I have even tagged it as a proper solution but then it turned out it is improper, because $(1 - \frac {k}{n})^n$ cannot be estimated by $e^{-k}$ because 
$(1 - \frac {k}{n})^n$ is not increasing for all natural numbers $n$.
Can anybody look at this problem again ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is infinity of the terms so we cannot use limits arithmetics.

Comment: @Alex:  but the number of terms is increasing, so that does not work.

Comment: Hint: $1^n + 2^n + \cdots + n^n \le \int_1^{n+1} x^n \, dx$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: squeeze lemma doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @Alex:  No, think of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n+\frac 1n+\frac 1n+\frac 1n+\frac 1n+\ldots$ where there are $n$ terms in the sum.  Each term goes to zero, but the sum is constant $1$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That's worth filling out to an answer.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n}$ looks very similar to a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {\sum_\limits{k=1}^n k^n}{n^n} = \frac {e}{e-1}$ is interesting.

but, $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {\sum_\limits{k=1}^n k^n}{n^{n+1}} = 0$
 is far less interesting.

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac {\sum_\limits{k=1}^n k^n}{n^n} = \frac {n^n + (n-1)^n + (n-2)^n \cdots}{n^n}\\
\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} 1 + (1 - \frac {1}{n})^n + (1 - \frac {2}{n})^n \cdots\\
1 + e^{-1} + e^{-2} + e^{-3} \cdots\\
\frac {e}{e-1}$

Answer (score 1):

By [Abel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{n}=n^{n+1}-n\int_{1}^{n}\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor t^{n-1}dt$$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor $ is the floor function and since $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor =t+O\left(1\right)$ we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{n}=n^{n+1}-n\int_{1}^{n}t^{n}dt+O\left(n^{n}\right)$$ $$=n^{n+1}-\frac{n}{n+1}\left(n^{n+1}-1\right)+O\left(n^{n}\right)=O\left(n^{n}\right)$$ then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{n}}{n^{n+1}}=\color{red}{0}.$$

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve it not using integration ? I mean, to use only standard estimations on natural numbers.